# Deriving the absorption coefficient from state transitions

Tags: spectroscopy, concentration

[This source](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Quantum_States_of_Atoms_and_Molecules_(Zielinksi_et_al.)/07%3A_Rotational_States/7.06%3A_Rotational_Spectroscopy_of_Diatomic_Molecules) states that the absorption coefficient $\gamma$ is proportional to the difference in particle number density $\Delta n$ per unit volume between the initial and the final rotational state and also proportional to the dipole moment $\mu_T$
$$\gamma \propto \Delta n\cdot \mu_T$$
According to the [Beer-Lambert Law](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Spectroscopy/Electronic_Spectroscopy/Electronic_Spectroscopy_Basics/The_Beer-Lambert_Law) the absorption coefficient is also equal to:
$$\gamma=\log_{10}\bigg(\frac{I_0}{I}\bigg)\cdot \frac{1}{c\cdot l}$$
Where $I_0$ and $I$ are the incidental and transmitted intensity, $c$ is the concentration of the solution and $l$ the traveled length through the solution by the incidental beam.

From this Beer-Lambert law I would deduce that the absorption coefficient is in terms of per 1 unit length and per 1 unit concentration.

I would assume that the difference in number density $\Delta n$ is analogous to the concentration of a solution.

But how is $\gamma$ then proportional to the $\Delta n$ if it should be per 1 unit of $\Delta n$ just as it is per 1 unit of sample concentration?

Comment: $\Delta n$ is the population difference between the two rotational states of the same molecule per unit volume and is mostly a function of temperature as dictated by the Boltzmann distribution.

Comment: @Paul In that case, I would assume that the _total_ number density of particles $N$ is the concentration $c$ instead and that the absorption coefficent $\gamma$ should be per 1 unit of $N$, correct? Such that the absorptivity $\log_{10}\bigg(\frac{I_0}{I}\bigg)$ is proportional to: $$\log_{10}\bigg(\frac{I_0}{I}\bigg)\propto \Delta n \cdot \mu_T \cdot N \cdot l$$ Is this correct?

Comment: When the population difference is zero there is no net absorption because of stimulated emission, i.e 'absorption' from the upper state to the lower state plus a photon. This is common in rotational spectroscopy where levels have very similar populations at room temperature, unlike in the uv -vis and near ir. The $\gamma$ in the second equation is the extinction coefficient, a property of the molecule and proportional to the transition dipole,  and not the same as in your first eqn, it seems that $\Delta n \mu\equiv \gamma c l$ but you should check.

Comment: @porphyrin The [source](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Spectroscopy/Electronic_Spectroscopy/Electronic_Spectroscopy_Basics/The_Beer-Lambert_Law) mentions right beneath **Example 1** that it can also be the absorption coefficient instead of the extinction coefficient. How is that possible?

Comment: These are different words for the same thing, it's best to look at how it is defined and then decide what it is. Not all authors use the same definition. Extinction coefficient is still very widely used in the scientific literature and textbooks.

Comment: @porphyrin In your derived equation $\Delta n \mu\equiv \gamma c$, is $\gamma$ the extinction or the absorption coefficient? Perhaps it's better to name them $\epsilon$ and $\alpha$ respectively. Based on the [relationship between Transmittance $T$ and Absorbance $A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmittance), I have deduced that $$\epsilon=\frac{A}{\ln(10^A)}\cdot \frac{\alpha}{c} = 0,434 \cdot \frac{\alpha}{c}$$ ..but I can't seem to match it with your derived equation.

Comment: Starting from scratch; $I=I_0e^{-\epsilon cl}$ is the Beer Lambert law where $I$ is transmitted intensity, $I_0$ initial amount, $\epsilon$ is the extinction coefficient , $c,l$ concentration and path length. $\epsilon c l$ is dimensionless. (in practice power 10 is used instead of e, it makes no odds). In your case you need $\Delta c$ not $c$ as there is population in both levels. $\epsilon$ is proportional to the transition dipole, thus $\epsilon \Delta c l \sim \mu \Delta c l $.

Comment: @porphyrin This has cleared it up for me, thanks! One last question, the [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_depth) says that $I=I_0e^{-\alpha \cdot l}$. Combining it with your mentioned $I=I_0e^{-\epsilon cl}$ means that $\alpha = \epsilon \cdot c$. But shouldn't this be $\alpha = \ln(10)\cdot \epsilon \cdot c$?

Comment: there are two definitions, one with powers of 10 , used in practice in spectrophotometers etc , and one base on powers of e , it does'n't matter which one is used as long as it is defined Normally the decadic extinction coefficient is quoted.